# cgminer freezes at random intervals

Tags: litecoin, cgminer, scrypt

I have just recently built a mining rig. The problem I am running into is that cgminer will randomly "freeze" while mining. When I say freeze cgminer will just stop accepting shares and the GPU data will stop updating; however, I am still able to issue the 'Q' command, but it does not work. I have tried everything I could think of to attempt to fix this problem. Re installing Xubuntu, lowering memclock, lowering engineclock, lowering intensity, lowering thread-concurrency, increasing voltage, upgrading/downgrading cgminer, etc. The odd thing is the fact that none of the cards crash or go sick before cgminer freezes, and you see no increase of GPU temps when cgminer does crash. The period of mining before crash seems to be completely random. It has crashed 30 seconds after startup and it has crashed 4 hours in (which was the longest uptime and it was on a higher memclock and engine clock than I am on now). To me this makes no sense why it would be crashing at all, for the cards seem perfectly stable with the settings.

System Specs:
CPU: FX 4130 quad core @ 3.8GHz, 8 MB Total Cache
PSU: HALE90 V2 1200W
GFX: 4x PowerColor HD7970 3GB GDDR5
RAM: Ballistix (by crucial) 4gb DDR3 1600MHz
SSD: SanDisk 64GB 6Gb/s
MOBO: 970 Extreme4 Socket AM3+ ATX AMD motherboard
OS: Xubuntu 12.10 x86_64

cgminer Start Parameters (start.sh script):
export DISPLAY=:0
export GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT=100
export GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS=1
./cgminer --scrypt -o http://poolurl.com:8080 -u username -p password -I 13 -g 2 -w 256 --auto-fan --temp-target 70 --temp-overheat 85 --gpu-fan 75-90 --thread-concurrency 8192 --gpu-engine 1106 --gpu-memclock 1825 --lookup-gap 2 --gpu-powertune 20

cgminer version is 3.7.2.

If you need any more information just ask. Any help will be appreciated, for I am absolutely stumped on what is causing the problem.

Thank you,
    Kyle

Comment: I have exactly the same issue! Don't know how to fix it yet....

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: just out of curiousity how much frequency are you getting

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

I d recommend to try bfgminer , a more secure and robust fork of cgminer :

http://bfgminer.org/

https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue, I think it has to do with the swapfile being enabled.  I went months without a freeze.  enabled swap file for BF4 bullshit coding, to play without directx out of memory error. Mining started freezing.  I thought I screwed up my cards.  Turned off swapfile on a whim and has been going for days now.  It would usually freeze in a few hours with swap file enabled.

Comment: This looks like a question than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems I've found kind a solution. Now my rig running for 16 hours without freezing. The only thing I did, I've placed --thread-concurrency 24000

Now my parameters are -I 20 --thread-concurrency 24000

And that's all.